# make svn maintain the file permission

Tags: linux, svn, permissions, file-permissions

I have some scripts that are supposed to be executable. But after it is checked into svn and checked out in another location, they lose their executable permission. One has to chmod it again. Even if one changes its permission already, next time when svn updates it, it loses its permission again. Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to inform SVN that the file should be executable:

```
svn propset svn:executable ON filename
```

and then commit this change.